# Resize images in Bitbucket wiki pages

Tags: bitbucket, markdown, restructuredtext

I'm trying to resize the images in the wiki pages and nothing is working: the images are always presented with 100% width of the page.

I tried with reStructuredText:

```
.. image:: image.jpeg
   :height: 100px
   :width: 200px
   :scale: 50 %
   :alt: alternate text
```

(and different combinations, ignoring some lines).

Then I also tried

```
![](image.jpeg =250x)
```

But, again, it doesn't change the size of the presented image.

Any idea?

Comment: Image resizing is currently not supported on BitBucket, see this open issue https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12877/markdown-support-for-display-of-readmemd

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoAddazi ! I thought it was just me

Answer (score 12):

> Bitbucket Server 7.5 includes support for defining the size of images in markdown.
>
> [...]
>
> The syntax which is supported is to specify the `height` and/or `width` as "key=value" pairs inside curly braces immediately after the markdown for the image, for example:

```markdown
![alt text for the image](image-file.png){width=50%}
![alt text for the image](image-file.png){height=50 width=60}
![alt text for the image](image-file.png){height=100}
![alt text for the image](image-file.png){width=200px}
```

See more at:  https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-7426

Comment: I am trying this by creating a README.md directly in repo and checking the preview, but the image sizes in preview is not changing.

Comment: hello @BitwiseDEVS, you may want to add a separate question with more details to it; I had tested this solution on bitbucket.org a while ago many times and it worked.

Comment: Could it be possible that changing image size does not reflect in preview and only when the changes is actually applied or commit?

Comment: Maybe you could try that on a temporary branch to see if it works

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it really is not working. Can you verify it on your end as well? I am confused as well since this is what they do in their doc. I am currently raising this [issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Resizing-image-is-not-working-in-README-md/qaq-p/2621678?utm_source=dm&utm_medium=unpaid-social&utm_campaign=P:online*O:community*I:social_share*) now.

Comment: I'm using Github now. I do remember having issues trying to edit `README.md` files on Bitbucket web editor, but it was something different. Maybe they're not giving this feature much love? My suggestion was trying the changes on a temp branch, but don't verify it on the commit preview: verify it by viewing the committed file.

Comment: I tried it, not working even in actual commit. It might be a bug or there is extra work needed.